# How to fill an array with holidays?

Tags: php, arrays, fill

It's about filling an array with holidays for a given year (not about how to calculate them), to easily get access to them afterwards. My approach is using the timestamps of the holidays as keys.

```
$year = 2015;
$holidays = array(
    strtotime($year . '-01-01') => array(
        'holiday' => 'New Year',
        'comment' => 'Happy New Year!'
    ),
    strtotime($year . '-04-05') => array(
        'holiday' => 'Easter',
        'comment' => 'Happy Easter!'
    ),
    strtotime($year . '-12-25') => array(
        'holiday' => 'Christmas',
        'comment' => 'Merry Christmas!'
    )
    .
    .
    .
);
```

This works fine until there is more than one holiday on one day at the same time, for example December 6, 2015 (St Nicholas' Day, First Advent). In that case, the value behind the key already defined gets overwritten. So another array level is needed.

```
$year = 2015;
$holidays = array();
$holidays[strtotime($year . '-01-01')][] => array(
        'holiday' => 'New Year',
        'comment' => 'Happy New Year!'
);
$holidays[strtotime($year . '-04-05')][] => array(
        'holiday' => 'Easter',
        'comment' => 'Happy Easter!'
);
$holidays[strtotime($year . '-12-25')][] => array(
        'holiday' => 'Christmas',
        'comment' => 'Merry Christmas!'
);
$holidays[strtotime($year . '-12-06')][] => array(
        'holiday' => 'St Nicholas\' Day',
        'comment' => 'Make sure to turn out your boots!'
);
$holidays[strtotime($year . '-12-06')][] => array(
        'holiday' => 'First Advent',
        'comment' => 'Remember to light the first candle on your Advent wreath!'
);
.
.
.
);
```

Can this array filling be done in "one line" (notice the `;`) as in my first example? Do you have other (smarter) ideas than my approach?

Comment: as holiday may vary depending on culture, religious and country, maybe using a library is a better idea. Or you can have an array to declare each holidays' detail and using `foreach` loop to fill `$holiday` array

Comment: What library would you suggest? Could you explain your second approach in detail as I don't really get it?

Comment: I cant recommend any library as I haven't tried myself, but google shows me this in the first page https://github.com/michalmanko/php-library-holiday

Comment: Thank you! But for my purpose, I think this would be cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular 0 indexed array and then create another field in the array for the holiday for the time.

```
$year = 2015;
$holidays = array();
$holidays[] => array(
        'holiday' => 'New Year',
        'comment' => 'Happy New Year!',
        'time' => strtotime($year . '-01-01')
);
$holidays[] => array(
        'holiday' => 'Easter',
        'comment' => 'Happy Easter!',
        'time' => strtotime($year . '-04-05'),
); 

...
```

Then if I need to sort it, I would use the php array sorting functions.

As for doing it all in one declaration, you could do something like this:

```
$holidays = array(
    strtotime($year . '-04-05') => array(
        array(
            'holiday' => 'Easter',
            'comment' => 'Happy Easter!',
        ),
        array(
            'holiday' => 'Christmas',
            'comment' => 'Merry Christmas!'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Just add more arrays all teh way down...

Comment: Of course, that approach I also had in mind, but it seems to be much more difficult and slower (going along with less performance) to get access to the holidays. When printing a calendar, yor example, you need to check, if the current date in your loop is a holiday. If the timestamps of the holidays are the keys, you only need to check, if the timestamp of the current date is set in the holiday array: `$currentDate = strtotime('today'); echo isset($holidays[$currentDate]) ? $holidays[$currentDate] : '';` Otherwise you would need to loop through the array for every single day, don't you?

Comment: What sorting functions do you mean? How would you do this?

Comment: Sorry, here are the sorting functions for arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: While performance also may be a concern, you can always refactor.  This should get you going.

Premature optimization may be a real thing for this, if you don't have too many holidays.

But if you're really concerned about it then the timestamp with sub-arrays would be the better option for you.

Comment: Regarding filling an array in one declaration, to do it like in your example, you need to know the days with more than one holiday, but as the holidays are calculated dynamically for each year, that's not appropriate.

Comment: Isn't sorting an array going along with pretty low-performance?

Comment: Right, but you already know the way to do it for the ones that are calculated dynamically.  You can do it both ways.  Set up the known-date holidays via static array but then add the ones calculated dynamically the way you did in your original example.

Comment: As for sorting performance you shouldn't be doing it more than once.

Comment: Premature optimization? I don't really understand how to apply this here.

Comment: As for doing it both ways combined, I would have to add onother array level in the static array for known-date holidays, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94452/discussion-between-kirkland-and-ben).